# Boto3: How to set the Marker parameter in the Bucket client in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

When you do

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')
objs = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket='my_bucket')
```

what you get in `objs['Contents']` are the very first 1000 results. In the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3#S3.Client.list_objects')) you can see a `Marker` parameter has to be set to paginate over all results, but it's not clear where to take its value from.

Does anyone know, for instance, how would I get the second page of results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the same documentation, under `NextMarker`, I discovered I have to use the value of the last retrieved key, i.e., the last `Key` in `objs['Contents']` as the next `Marker`.